# Debug a real Android device using Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: sqlite, mvvm, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I'm a beginner in mobile development, and I'm developing an application in Xamarin.Android with Visual Studio 2019, with SQLite and the MVVM pattern. The project structure is simple, I'm not using API's or external services. For debugging, I'm trying to use my physical device (Android 9.0 - API 28, Itel S15 tag), but unfortunately the following error message is returned in Visual Studio (Debug output):

```
Forwarding debugger port 8865
Failed to launch android application
```

it's the first time i've tried this, i've always debugged in an installed emulator,I have USB debugging enabled as well as developer mode on the physical device. I've done a lot of research and I can't find anything specific to my problem. Please any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before debugging can occur on a device, it must be setup for development and connected to your PC or Mac.

Here are documents about how you can set up the device and how to debug on device
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-device?tabs=windows

Comment: Thank you so much for the links. I retraced the steps, but the error remains.

Comment: Have you install the same instance on your phone? if you do, delete all the instances.

Comment: Also, Try this: Double-click Android properties, under the Android Options page,Click the Advanced button and, under Supported architectures, select all supported ABIs

Comment: I just had it installed when trying to deploy, but I already deleted it.

Comment: I already had these options selected(all supported ABIs), but continue. :(

Comment: may this blog would help you https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-debug-on-real-android-device-using-xamarin-visual-studio

Comment: Thank You Adrain.. Finally solved my problem..